# epslatex graph problem

Tags: graphics

I am using the [`epslatex`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/epslatex/english) image generated by `gnuplot` in my LaTeX document for example if I have a picture `example.tex`, I use it in LaTeX as

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\input{example}
\end{figure}
```

The above command is working well in the normal document class. But I am writing a paper for AIAA and they have a class name `aiaa.cls` in which the picture when Imported by above command appears really weird. The axis labels and image run here and there.

Could someone suggest me whats wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`) or hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: It is unlikely to be related to the class file used, however if you mean you really used the name `example` that might be a problem as it is quite likely there are several files of that name on the system and you may pick up the wrong one.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the above problem by using 'pslatex' terminal instead of 'epslatex' in gnuplot.

Comment: But then only the .tex will be created?
How have you include the the picture?